# setTimeout inside useEffect with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, settimeout

I have array of objects inside my useState hook, and I would like to change one property of each array element let's say it looks like:

```
const array = [{id:1, isDisplayed: false}, {id:2, isDisplayed: false}, {id:3, isDisplayed: true}]
```

and while Im trying to use `setTimeout` inside `useEffect` hook to change property `displayed` everywhere where it's not `true` to `isDisplayed: true` , it waits for the dedicated time, and changes everything at once, what I want to achieve is to change each element with its own delay. I mean something like
`const DELAY = 2000` and inside setTimeout for instance `setTimeout(() => ... , DELAY * id)`
because in place when I render jsx, everything appears all at once, and i just want to make small delays between appearing each element. For instance, first element appears after 2s, second after 3s (not 3s after first one)

My current code looks like:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
 setTimeout(() => {
  setArray(array.map((item)=> !item.isDisplayed ? {...item, displayed: true} : item))
 }, DELAY * Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
}, [])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a timeout and trigger an update, if some items are not visible.

And track if new items are revealed with `revealed` and if no new items were revealed, stop the flow.

```
function TodoApp() {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([
    { id: 1, isDisplayed: false },
    { id: 2, isDisplayed: false },
    { id: 3, isDisplayed: false },
  ]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let currentTimeout = null;
    const displayMoreItems = () => {
      setItems(prevItems => {
        let revealed = false;
        const nextItems = prevItems.map(item => {
          if (!revealed && !item.isDisplayed) {
            revealed = true;
            return { ...item, isDisplayed: true };
          }
          return item;
        });
        if (revealed) {
          currentTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            displayMoreItems();
          }, 1000);
        }
        return nextItems;
      });
    };
    currentTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      displayMoreItems();
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      if (currentTimeout) {
        clearTimeout(currentTimeout);
      }
    };
  }, [setItems]);
  return <div>{items.map(item => (item.isDisplayed ? item.id : null))}</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jrn3ubef/2/)

Comment: I would recommend to cancel any timeouts in the return value as function of the useEffect

Comment: Yes thats true, but since its just a mock

Comment: in place where you have ```if(revealed){...}``` my eslint says ```"Unnecessary conditional, value is always falsy.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition"```  the declaration of ```revelated``` must be moved line above ```setItems```

Comment: The closures are fine. It does not amtter.

Comment: nvm it working fine when i moved this line, all depends on ur eslint restrictions :) accepted as desired answer Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
const DELAY = 2000;
React.useEffect(() => {
 let count = 1;
 array.forEach((item) => {
   if (!item.displayed) {
     setTimeout(() => {
        item.displayed = true;
        setArray([...array]);
     }, DELAY * count);
     count ++;
   }
 })
}, [])
```

Comment: This would mutate the items and will not cause a rerender

Comment: exactly it wont trigger rerender which is main goal in here